# how can change some item view in recyclerview adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a RecyclerView and a button in different layout. Now, I want to change all item views with setonclicklistener  ?
for example when i  setonclick listener method all item views gone button expect this item that was clicked on it

Comment: then perform onclickListner in the adapter

Answer (score 0):

**For one Line question here is One line Answer**

Reload/Clear the recyclerView on `onClick()` of your View or set the different Adapter and clear the previous according to you.

Comment: i explained more in my question

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new activity and have same layout as of the recyclerview. when you click on the item, you can send data of that row using bundle. retrieve bundle data and set on the newly created activity's components

Answer (score 0):

**If i got your questin:**

when click button you want to change itemView layout

```
    buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
        LocationListAdapter adapter=new LocationListAdapter(this,R.layout.layout_one,  addressList); 
        locationListRecyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);   
        }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the adapter with new one, on the click listener of button and if you do not want to change the whole view of the item then update the list binding to your current adapter and notify the adapter in the click listener.